# Observable Not Running on a Different Thread

Tags: java, asynchronous, rx-java

I am experimenting a bit with RxJava. Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    List<String> l = new ArrayList<>();
    l.add("737");
    l.add("747");

    Observable.from(l)
        .doOnNext(
            a -> {
              System.out.println(
                  "1: "
                      + a
                      + ", Thread:"
                      + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                      + " Timestamp: "
                      + System.currentTimeMillis());
            })
        .flatMap(
            a -> {
              System.out.println(
                  "2: "
                      + a
                      + ", Thread:"
                      + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                      + " Timestamp: "
                      + System.currentTimeMillis());
              return Observable.just(a).subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread());
            })
        .map(
            a -> {
              if (a.equals("737")) {
                try {
                  Thread.sleep(20000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
                }
              }
              return a;
            })
        .map(
            a -> {
              System.out.println(
                  "3: "
                      + a
                      + ", Thread: "
                      + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                      + " Timestamp: "
                      + System.currentTimeMillis());
              return a.concat(" Boeing");
            })
        .reduce(
            new ArrayList<>(),
            (a, b) -> {
              System.out.println(
                  "4: "
                      + b
                      + ", Thread: "
                      + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                      + " Timestamp: "
                      + System.currentTimeMillis());
              a.add(b);
              return a;
            })
        .subscribe(
            a -> {
              System.out.println(
                  "4: "
                      + a
                      + ", Thread: "
                      + Thread.currentThread().getName()
                      + " Timestamp: "
                      + System.currentTimeMillis());
              System.out.println("Reduce result is: " + a);
            });

    Thread.sleep(500000);  //to prevent the main thread from exiting
  }
```

Here's an output of the above code:

```
1: 737, Thread:main Timestamp: 1546369697211
2: 737, Thread:main Timestamp: 1546369697211
1: 747, Thread:main Timestamp: 1546369697235
2: 747, Thread:main Timestamp: 1546369697235
3: 737, Thread: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 Timestamp: 1546369717238
4: 737 Boeing, Thread: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 Timestamp: 1546369717238
3: 747, Thread: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 Timestamp: 1546369717239
4: 747 Boeing, Thread: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 Timestamp: 1546369717239
4: [737 Boeing, 747 Boeing], Thread: RxNewThreadScheduler-1 Timestamp: 1546369717239
Reduce result is: [737 Boeing, 747 Boeing]
```

My question is if the 737 is running on the thread `RxNewThreadScheduler-1` and this thread is sleeping for 20 seconds, the 747 thread should have continued execution, right? But in the output we can see that the output corresponding to '3' for 747 comes later than for 737. Further, this operator is getting called on the same thread as 737.

To put it more precisely, why is the '3' for 747 running only after the thread for 737 has woken up? It would appear as it 747 is trying to use the same threads as 737. As I understand this, the flow should have been:

1. 737 observable is emitted on thread A, which immediately sleep for 20s.
2. 747 is emitted on thread B, and it continues execution.
3. Operations corresponding to 747 should have completed earlier on a different thread.

Can someone explain this behaviour to me?

Comment: It would be interesting to include a log in a `doOnSubscribe` of the `just(a).subscribeOn(...)` observables in the flatMap function.

Comment: The expression `Schedulers.newThread()` may only be returning a scheduler with a single thread in it. Are you overriding how schedulers are provisioned? Other than that, please follow Janos' advice about logging.

Comment: This is not a minimal example. remove the second `map`, operator fusing could play a part. Remove the `reduce` and see if you're still getting similar results. Try and get your threads to have different names so you know they are different.

Comment: Use `blockingSubscribe` instead of `Thread.sleep(500000);`

Comment: as per @JanosBreuer advise about logging, maybe create a logging method, it would reduce the code by 85% and make it easier to read!